# Jenkins: remove repo after build, keep only log

Tags: jenkins, space, disk

Jenkins is checking out my projects' repositories every time for each build and each PR. This quickly fills up the disk (only 10Gb) as each checkout amounts to 300Mb and there are 5 projects (all in range of 300-500Mb per project). We've already set `Discard old items` with empty values but it doesn't seem to delete the files once the PR has another build.

I've noticed the files are stored at:
`/data/versioning/config/jobs/MyProjectAbc/branches/PR-9424/workspace@script/`
Is there an option for Jenkins to delete the whole `PR-xxxx/workspace@script` folder and only keep the `PR-xxxx/builds` folder?

Lightweight checkouts currently aren't possible (possibly because of outdated plugin, `Bitbucket Branch Source 2.2.8`)

Comment: Is wiping the workspace after the build an option? Or deleting certain directories? Is a Jenkins Pipeline?

Comment: No, wiping workspace is not an option for those jobs. It's a pipeline indeed. There's only the option to discard old items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/) as a post-step in your pipeline to clear out the workspace after each build.

Something like:

```
pipeline {
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for deleting the `..@script` folder that's created on the controller. It would seem that cleanWs only cleans the workspace on the agent.

Comment: This answer is over four years old. Perhaps the plugin has been changed? I see it has a `deleteDirs` option now. Maybe try that?

Comment: No, I tried `deleteDirs` too. It's ok, it's not serious problem for me. Thanks tho